# Как получить номер столбца QCheckBox?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить номер QCheckBox, если на неё нажал пользователь?

Я юзаю QTableWidget

код:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent, uint appId)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui_(new Ui::Widget)
    , appId_(appId)
    , processing_window_(new ProcessingWindow())
    , isAllSelected_ (false)
{

    ui_->setupUi (this);

    connect (ui_->pushButton, // "Store Button" clicked
             SIGNAL (clicked()),
             this,
             SLOT (OnStoreButtonClicked ())
             );

    connect (ui_->selectAllButton, // "Select All" button clicked
             SIGNAL (clicked ()),
             this,
             SLOT (OnSelectAllButtonPressed())
             );

    if (!SteamAPI_Init())
    {
        std::cerr << "Error! Couldn't initialize SteamApi!";
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    achievements_ = GetAchievementsList();


    ui_->tableWidget->setColumnCount (4);
    ui_->tableWidget->setRowCount (achievements_.size ());

    ui_->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderItem (0, new QTableWidgetItem ("Icon") );
    ui_->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderItem (1, new QTableWidgetItem ("Name") );
    ui_->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderItem (2, new QTableWidgetItem ("Description") );
    ui_->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderItem (3, new QTableWidgetItem ("Achieved") );

    // Resizing the 'description' header
    ui_->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode (2, QHeaderView::Stretch);


    // Make the table widget not editable
    ui_->tableWidget->setEditTriggers (QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);


    for (uint i = 0; i < achievements_.size(); ++i)
    {
        QIcon icon = GetAchievementIcon (achievements_[i].api_name);

        ui_->tableWidget->setIconSize (QSize ( 50, 50 ) );

        ui_->tableWidget->setRowHeight (static_cast<int> (i), 60);

        ui_->tableWidget->setItem (static_cast<int>(i), 0, new QTableWidgetItem (icon, "") );

        ui_->tableWidget->setItem(static_cast <int> (i), 1, // Achivement's name
                         new QTableWidgetItem ( achievements_[i].name.c_str() ) );

        ui_->tableWidget->setItem (static_cast <int> (i), 2, // Description
                         new QTableWidgetItem (achievements_[i].description.c_str() ) );

        QCheckBox *check_box = new QCheckBox();

        // checkBoxes - вектор ссылок на QCheckBox
        checkBoxes_.push_back (check_box);

        // Placing Check Boxes...

        QWidget *widget = new QWidget ();

        QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout (widget);

        check_box->setChecked (achievements_[i].is_unlocked);

        layout->addWidget (check_box);

        layout->setAlignment (Qt::AlignCenter);

        layout->setContentsMargins (0, 0, 0, 0);

        widget->setLayout (layout);

        ui_->tableWidget->setCellWidget (static_cast <int> (i), 3, widget);
    }

}
```

Comment: Сложно по скриншоту угадать каким виджетом вы там пользуетесь (наверняка QTableView или QTableWidget) и как вы разместили QCheckBox (cell-widget или через делегаты), поэтому добавьте код в вопрос :)

Comment: упс, точно. сейчас подправлю вопрос. спасибо

Comment: Четвертый ) А вам для чего? Смотрите, если бы это была какая-то динамическая таблица где стоблцы и их тип постоянно меняются, то еще понятно. А в данном случае у вас есть изначальная "статическая" структура таблицы и не совсем понятно, почему у вас возник такой вопрос?

Comment: Есть такая программка, называется SAM (Steam Achievements Manager). Она доступна для Windwos, но нет норм порта на Linux, и поэтому я пытаюсь сделать порт данной программы для любимого Линукс. Как работает вот эта программа? Пользователь может поставить галочку, а может убрать. Если галочка стоит, то это достижение будет "накручено" пользователю, а если нет, то наоборот -- заблокировано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там где Вы складываете указатели на чекбоксы в вектор, дополнительно подпишите их на слот.

```
// checkBoxes - вектор ссылок на QCheckBox
checkBoxes_.push_back (check_box);
connect(check_box, &QAbstractButton::toggled, this, &Widget::slot);
```

Сделайте слот, который будет принимать сигнал от чекбокса. Пробегите по ранее созданному вектору, сравнивая каждый объект в нем с sender().

```
void Widget::slot(bool toggled)
{
    for (qint32 i = 0; i < checkBoxes_.size(); ++i) {
        if (checkBoxes_.at(i) == qobject_cast<QCheckBox *>(sender())) {
            qDebug() << "номер чекбокса" << i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В `for` будет какой-нибудь `checkBoxes_.size()`

Comment: Именно так. Поправил.